# Текст должен растягивать блок по высоте, а кнопка должна

Tags: html, css

Проект не проходит тест на переполнение контента:

> Текст должен растягивать блок по высоте, а кнопка должна оставаться на своём месте.

Если использую у родителя `flex-wrap`, то кнопка съезжает со своего места, если убираю `flex-wrap`, то кнопку выталкивает за пределы родительского контейнера.

```css
.all-header-popular {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f9f5f0;
  width: 100%;
}

.popular-title {
  width: 264px;
  margin: 31px 0px 31px 28px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #32425c;
}

.popular-subtitle {
  background-color: #ee3643;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.29;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0px 24px 0 0px;
  width: 253px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-header-popular">
  <h3 class="popular-title">Популярные товары:</h3>
  <h3 class="popular-title">Популярные товары:</h3>
  <h3 class="popular-title">Популярные товары:</h3>
  <a href="#" class="popular-subtitle">Все популярные товары</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, пришлите код, который в итоге у Вас получился в виде ответа. Интересно посмотреть

Comment: https://codepen.io/paradox244/pen/eYYeXBz?editors=1100 решение